# Can't ping in RHEL 7 in VMware pro

Tags: linux, administrator, vmware-workstation, redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-7

Image of the network card configuration:

[image: Image of the network card configuration]

This is RHEL - 7 in VMware-workstation 17 pro, I'm trying to ping the gateway of the same IP and `google.com`. I have no idea what's the issue as my friend uses same machine and same version of Red Hat but he can ping.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. I have VMware Pro V17 here.

Make sure for sure the RHEL network setup is NOT Host Only.

For external access, Bridged Networking is best.  NAT is trickier for this.

Make sure you are working by IP Address and not Computer Name